# Resizing and operator= overloading

Tags: c++, pointers, resize, variable-assignment, operator-keyword

I've implemented a class named LipidType but the program crashes when the resize function and assignment operator overloading are called but I can't find out the error in the code. These are the private members of the class

```
private:
    std::string *mod;
    std::string *classe;
    int matches;
    double mz;
    double *intensity;
    double *frag;
    std::string name;
    int maxsize;
    int length;
```

and these are the functions

```
LipidType& LipidType::operator=(const LipidType& otherlip)  //assignment operator
{
if (this == &otherlip) return *this; // handle self assignment

if(otherlip.maxsize > maxsize)
{
    std::cout << "Resizing" << std::endl;
    resize(otherlip.maxsize);
}

for(int i=0; i<otherlip.length; i++)
{
    mod[i]=otherlip.mod[i];
    classe[i]=otherlip.classe[i];
    intensity[i]=otherlip.intensity[i];
    frag[i]=otherlip.frag[i];
}

matches=otherlip.matches;
name=otherlip.name;
mz=otherlip.mz;

length = otherlip.length;

return *this;
}

void LipidType::resize(int nusize)
{
    maxsize = nusize;
    std::string* temp1=new std::string[maxsize];
    std::string* temp2=new std::string[maxsize];
    double* temp3=new double[maxsize];
    double* temp4=new double[maxsize];

    for(int i=0; i<length; i++)
    {
        temp1[i]=mod[i];
        temp2[i]=classe[i];
        temp3[i]=intensity[i];
        temp4[i]=frag[i];
    }

    delete [] mod;
    delete [] classe;
    delete [] intensity;
    delete [] frag;

    mod=temp1;
    classe=temp2;
    intensity=temp3;
    frag=temp4;
 }
```

Comment: I'll bet you those pointers are unnecessary.

Comment: How do you add items to your source (`otherlip`) object? I mean, can `maxsize` occidentally become lower than `length`?

Comment: I add the items (pointers) through function that increase length (length++) and if length+1>maxsize calls the resize function

Comment: might I intrest you in [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)? Also consider having another type, which holds 2 stdings and 2 doubles as elements, so you have only one container to consider

Comment: Which type can hold strings and doubles in only one container?

Comment: @RiccardoDiguida, `boost::variant`.